# Are all memories shared between Dax symbiont?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

On *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*: "Facets," Jadzia Dax finally makes plans to undergo her Zhian'tara, in which she has the chance to actually meet her previous hosts by temporarily transferring each one's memories from the symbiont into the minds of each of her closest friends.

During the episode we learn that Curzon was in love with Jadzia.

Why didn't Jadzia know this? Aren't all memories shared once the symbiont is joined?

Comment: Evidently not. If you'd asked the question without the example, that's the example I'd have used to show that individual memories can be withheld.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

We see several times where Jadzia was surprised by a memory Dax had, most notably of [Joran Dax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Joran_Dax) (whose existence proved that the symbiotes were compatible with most Trills, not just the selected few).

The existence of the [Zhian'tara](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zhian%27tara) in the episode "[Facets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Facets_(episode))"  more or less proves the memories are limited. Why have a ceremony to reminisce with old hosts if you have all their memories?

We also see from the episode "[Field of Fire](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Field_of_Fire_(episode))" (where Ezri Dax pulls Joran out into her consciousness) that hosts can "bury" prior hosts to some extent, which implies some control over memories as well ([screenplay](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/563.htm), emphasis mine)

> EZRI: Chzui vok Ezri sheyhal bashar. I'nora ja'kala vok.
>   JORAN: I can't tell you how much I've enjoyed our time together.
>   EZRI: Zheem Dax nah sass eye ahn. D'za oo bah zheest. Joran rhee jehr hey dah
>   JORAN: **You won't be able to forget me or bury me as deeply as Curzon or Jadzia did.**
>   EZRI: I know.
>   JORAN: I'm part of you now. As much as Audrid, Torias, any of them.
>   EZRI: I'll have to be careful. Tu Dax noh zhian 'vok j'zui.
>   (Joran fades away.)
>   EZRI: Joran rhem tanas Ezri.